# Initiate CMD console for executable created by cx_Freeze in Python

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have created an application in Python and have made it executable using `cx_Freeze`.

When the script was not converted into an executable it used to take an input from the `cmd` (in windows). However, when it is converted into exe it doesn't prompt me for an input.

I have used the following code as `setup.py` for my script.

```
    includefiles = ["checkPointValueSheets.py"] # include any files here that you wish
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ["lxml"]

exe = Executable(
 # what to build
   script = "app.py", # the name of your main python script goes here 
   initScript = None,
   base = None, # if creating a GUI instead of a console app, type "Win32GUI"
   targetName = "aflPredictionAutomation.exe", # this is the name of the executable file
   copyDependentFiles = True,
   compress = True,
   appendScriptToExe = True,
   appendScriptToLibrary = True,
   icon = None # if you want to use an icon file, specify the file name here
)

setup(
 # the actual setup & the definition of other misc. info
    name = "app", # program name
    version = "0.1",
    description = 'A general enhancement utility',
    author = "K Perkins",
    author_email = "",
    options = {"build_exe": {"excludes":excludes,"packages":packages,
      "include_files":includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]
)
```

Please help me initiating the cmd console the moment I hit enter on my exe.

I am getting this error when executable is run..

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is allready in the comment in your code (and in [cx_Freeze’s documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html), you should simply comment the 2 lines

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
```

If you let `base = None` your exe will be a console application (and not a GUI one) and Windows will automatically provide it with a new console if not allready started from one.

Comment: I have commented the lines and edited my question code too. Actually the error screen shot is coming as it cannot `import name _elementpath `
It is coming from the line 
`import lxm.html `
in my source code. Can you help? The script runs fine on cmd.

Comment: It is now a totally different problem : you have to tell cx_freeze the module you use. You can have a look at this other post as a way to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639429/cx-freeze-module-dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639429/cx-freeze-module-dependency)

Comment: The page doesn't have anything

Comment: I have solved the above problem, but now it says that permission is denied while openning a file where in I used to write logs.. 

What can be the issue?

Comment: Could it be a problem of current directory not being what you expect ?