# Can't run exe created by CX_Freeze

Tags: python, selenium, cx-freeze

I've been using cx-freeze to create an executable from a set of Python scripts. The setup.py looks like the following

```
    import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import PIL
import os


include_files = []
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
        Executable("bot.py", base=base)
]

buildOptions = dict(
        packages = [],
        includes = [],
        include_files = include_files,
        excludes = []
)




setup(
    name = "bot",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "windows",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
 )
```

Then i use build from command line:

```
python setup.py build
```

Then the Build file is cretead but when i open it that file i got that error:

```
    cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
xj
Traceback(most recent call last):
File
"C:\Users\Kratos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python33\lib\si
te-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
module. run()
File
"C:\Users\Kratos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\si te-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
exec(code, {'_name____'___main___'})
File "bot.py", line 88, in <module>
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

Is something incorrect in my code? What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: error show problem in `bot.py` in line `88`. What do you have in this line?  `input()`? This need access to `stdin` so it has to be run in console/terminal/cmd.exe. Do you run .exe in console/terminal/cmd.exe ?

Comment: and how can i insert an input() running .exe?

Comment: if you want to use `input()` then don't click `.exe` but open console/terminal/cmd.exe and manually run it. If you want to run by click then don't use `input()` but create some `GUI` using `tkinter`, `PyQt` or other GUI framework.

Comment: see also [Initiate CMD console for executable created by cx_Freeze in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242567/initiate-cmd-console-for-executable-created-by-cx-freeze-in-python)